# Modifying adjectives: カンペキ [に or な?] 思ったとおりの仕上がり

Tags: grammar

I have a question about カンペキに in the following sentence. As far as I can guess it modifies the whole 「思ったとおりの仕上がり」, but grammatically I cannot understand why. Well, 仕上がり is a noun, so wouldn't カンペキな be correct here?

> お母さまを真似して作ってみたんだけど、カンペキに思ったとおりの仕上がりなの
>
> "It came out perfectly just like I thought it should!"

Comment: Isn't 「カンペキ」 or 「完璧」 in its adverbial form in this sentence?

(Just clarifying if you realize this so answering would be easier.)

Comment: Yeah of course, I realize it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「[思]{おも}ったとおりの[仕上]{しあ}がり」 is a noun phrase.  Why?  Because the last word 「仕上がり」is a noun.

「カンペキに」 is the [連用形]{れんようけい} and therefore, it cannot modify a noun or noun phrase.  It can only modify a verb or adjective.  To modify a noun, you will need to form a [連体形]{れんたいけい}, which will be 「カンペキな」.

「思ったとおりの」 is an adjectival phrase because of the last word 「の」 and it is what「カンペキに」 modifies here.　「思ったとおりの」 naturally modifies 「仕上がり」.

> In the sentence, 「カンペキに思ったとおりの仕上がりなの。」, you could actually replace the 「に」 with 「な」 without changing the meaning much.

If you used 「カンペキな」, both 「カンペキな」 and 「思ったとおりの」 would modify 「仕上がり」.

Comment: Wow, that's really interesting.
Thanks everyone for help!

Comment: So in short, it's being used as an adverb to modify the verb that's been converted to an adjective to modify the noun.

Comment: @Kaji I don't think it's modifying the verb. Nothing was "thought perfectly". Rather, it's modifying the whole adjectival phrase, which just happens to contain a verb. Compare 完璧に素敵な一日だった。 "It was a wonderful day _in all respects_".

Comment: To clarify, by modifying the verb I meant that they thought it was perfect, not that they were thinking perfectly.  Which actually begs the question why not use と instead of either に or な in this case...

Comment: @Kaji, it's being used as an adverb to modify the verb, な (copula rentaikei).

Answer (score 3):

完璧 doesn't "modify" 仕上がり here, it is used adverbially. The difference is a little hard to translate, because 仕上がり is usually not translated literally (at least not for cakes). If we tried, we'd have something like

> 思ったとおりの**完璧な**仕上がりなの
> *lit.* It's a **perfect** "finish", just as I thought.
> It came out perfectly, just as I thought.
>
> **完璧な**思ったとおりの仕上がりなの
> *lit.* It's a **perfect** "finish-I-imagined".
> It came out perfect in the way I imagined.
>
> **完璧に**思ったとおりの仕上がりなの
> *lit.* It's **exactly** the "finish" I imagined.
> It came out exactly the way I imagined.

From the translation you have, it looks like it should be 完璧**な**. I think the best way to think of it is that 完璧**に** is used to mean "exactly".

Comment: Oops, too late.

Comment: Anyway, thank you very much for your reply.

Comment: This is the best answer. It's 完璧に (an adverb), not 完璧な (an adjective) because it's not a "perfect result" but "a result which matches expectations perfectly"

Comment: I think the important "easy to miss" nuance here that 思う is taking the more creative meaning of "imagine" rather than just "think".