# Modifying adjectives 「のように」

Tags: grammar

I cannot understand what exactly is ように modifying in the following sentence. And is it grammatically possible for 流れる濁流のよう to modify 急激な感情の? Because in phrase like this - 完璧に思ったとおりの仕上がり, 完璧に modifies  思ったとおりの. It is the [question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14937/modifying-adjectives-%E3%82%AB%E3%83%B3%E3%83%9A%E3%82%AD-%E3%81%AB-or-%E3%81%AA-%E6%80%9D%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E3%81%A8%E3%81%8A%E3%82%8A%E3%81%AE%E4%BB%95%E4%B8%8A%E3%81%8C%E3%82%8A) I've asked some time ago. But in this sentence it's also 急激な which modifies 感情, so I'm not sure if it's correct.

> 一人残された俺は考えを巡らせている。どうしようもなく流れる濁流のように急激な感情の波を止められずにいる。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would parse it as

> [(どうしようもなく)流れる][(濁流のように)急激な]感情の波

(The relative clause どうしようもなく流れる and the adjectival phrase 濁流のように急激な both modify the noun phrase 感情の波)

... or maybe...

> [{(どうしようもなく流れる)濁流のように}急激な]感情の波

(The relative clause どうしようもなく流れる modifies 濁流, the adverbial phrase どうしようもなく流れる濁流のように modifies 急激な and どうしようもなく流れる濁流のように急激な modifies 感情の波)

Comment: すみませんが、どっちか分かりません。

Comment: ありがとうございした。
本当に勉強になった答えです。

Comment: 個人的には、後者の解釈がより自然ではないかと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます、TNのおじ・・・じゃなくて、Hのおにいさま♡

Answer (score 2):

～のように can be used to set up a metaphor, as is being done in your sample sentence.  In this case, the ～のように phrase is essentially a parallel construction and doesn't directly modify any specific thing in the rest of the sentence, serving instead to establish the overall mood or scene.

- 一人残された俺は考えを巡らせている。 **どうしようもなく流れる濁流のように** 急激な感情の波を止められずにいる。
  Left on my own, I stir up my thoughts.  **Like a muddy current flowing along aimlessly,** I cannot stop the sudden waves of emotion.

If I were to diagram the latter sentence, it might look like the following, where each bit to the left and above modifies the next thing to the right and below.

```
どうしようもなく
　　　　　　流れる
　　　　　　　　　濁流の
　　　　　　　　　　　　ように
```

(the above is the metaphor)

```
急激な
　　　感情の
　　　　　　波を
　　　　　　　　止められずに
　　　　　　　　　　　　　　いる。
```